# C++: is std::conjunction supposed to work with inputs that are explicitly convertible to bool?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20, type-traits

In the C++20 standard, [[meta.logical]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/meta.logical) is careful to explicitly convert the inputs to `conjunction`, `disjunction`, and `negation` to `bool`. For example:

> The specialization `conjunction<B1, …, BN>` has a public and unambiguous base that is either
>
> - the first type `Bi` in the list `true_­type`, `B1`, …, `BN` for which `bool(Bi​::​value)` is false, or
> - [...]

I thought this was intended to allow inputs with a `value` member that is only explicitly convertible to bool, such as

```cpp
struct MyBool {
  constexpr explicit operator bool() { return false; }
};

struct WeirdTrait {
  static constexpr MyBool value;
};
```

But according to [[meta.logical]/5.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/meta.logical#5.1) and similar clauses the resulting type's `value` member should be exactly the first "falsey" input's `value` member, and this shouldn't work with the [definition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/meta.type.synop#lib:conjunction_v) of `conjunction_v`:

```cpp
template<class... B>
  inline constexpr bool conjunction_v = conjunction<B...>::value;
```

This doesn't work with a type like `MyBool`, since it requires the ability to do an implicit conversion to `bool`.

**I see how this works for inputs that are integral constants, but is it intended to work for other inputs that are explicitly convertible to `bool`?**

I thought perhaps the answer was in [[meta.rqmts]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/meta.rqmts) which sort of implies that all "type traits" must all be specializations of `integral_constant`. But there is no precise definition of that term as far as I can tell, and also it doesn't specifically say that `conjunction` must take a "type trait" as an input. Also, this is silly, but I can't actually find any requirement that `integral_constant` only be used with integral types.

Comment: How do you get to `MyBool::value`?

Comment: It doesn't matter; that's not the point of the question. The question would still apply if the body were just `return false`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you're asking. The point is that there could be some other type trait-like struct that itself had a `MyBool value` member. I've edited the question to show that now.

Comment: `MyBool` is not convertible to `bool`, at least not [as defined by `std::is_convertible`](https://godbolt.org/z/5j5W7z17Y). Whereas [**\[meta.logical\]/4**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/meta.logical#4) says "Every template type argument for which `Bi​::​value` is instantiated ... shall have a member `value` which is convertible to `bool`"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Sounds like a reasonable answer; you should probably post it as one.

Comment: *can be convertible to * doesnt mean `can be explicitly convertible to`

Comment: That's a good point. But I can't find any precise definition of "convertible to" except [conv.general/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.general#4) which specifically covers conversion to `bool` and _does_ cover `WeirdTrait::value`. It's also defined in exactly the same way as the use in the definition of `std::conjunction`.